# Standard work-around for using a Solidity constant array (which is not supported) in pure function?

Tags: solidity, arrays, view, constant, pure

I have an array in my contract like this and a pure method which uses it like this (simplified exmaple because my real exmaple is many more lines):

```
uint[16] constant x = [10, 2, 6, 42, 19, 5, 4, 36, 6, 6, 5, 5, 5, 46, 4, 4];

function foo(uint i, uint j) external pure returns (uint) {
    return x[i] + x[j] * 12;
}
```

But solidity doesn't seem to support this, so I can only figure out to change it to non constant, but then I'm foreced to switch to view even though my function is pure.

```
uint[16] x = [10, 2, 6, 42, 19, 5, 4, 36, 6, 6, 5, 5, 5, 46, 4, 4];

function foo(uint i, uint j) external view returns (uint) {
    return x[i] + x[j] * 12;
}
```

it seems I can only keep the funciton pure if I changd it in to a bunch of seperate uint insted of uint[16] but that's messy.

Is there a workaorund which keeps my function pure? Is just making it view the standard work-around to this?

Comment: Yes, `view` is the current solution to this, but please note that both `pure` and `view` are considered constant functions.

Comment: Can keep it pure if the array is defined as memory array inside the function.
uint[16] memory x = [10, 2, 6....

Answer (score 4):

It seems that is an pending feature
https://github.com/ethereum/solidity/issues/1772

However, if the desired range is from 0-255, there is a trick for you.

```
bytes public constant TEST_MAP = hex"000804";
   
function test(uint8 key) external pure returns (byte) {
   return TEST_MAP[uint256(key)];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I think that this should work.

```
pragma solidity >=0.7.0 <0.9.0;

contract MyContract {

    function foo(uint i, uint j) external pure returns (uint) {
        uint8[16] memory x = [10, 2, 6, 42, 19, 5, 4, 36, 6, 6, 5, 5, 5, 46, 4, 4];
        return x[i] + x[j] * 12;
    }
}
```